# Why is there viewstate on my MVC 2.0 page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewstate

sorry if this is a dumb question but i thought the whole thing with MVC was that there was no viewstate (or the choice to not have viewstate), yet when i create my page i have this:

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNDMyNDU0NjAzZGRjlqkQNPIdYgfiR4aOw7np3SRI0LRCffrTkaOLWtatvA==" />
```

how do i get rid of it?

Comment: Is this a clean project?  I've heard of this when 3rd party components are included in the project that weren't written for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Edit your question to include the contents of the View that you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for any `runat="server"` tag in all your pages (master, views, controls, ...) and remove it (especially things like `<form runat="server">`). Those attributes should no longer be present in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: This is not 100% true. WebForms View Engine (He's using MVC2) still uses runat="server" for sections (asp:content)

Comment: @Linkgoron, you are correct, very good point. Indeed those shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Darin, there was a runat tag in my form. I removed it and it fixed the problems. My user controls in the page have the runat tag also but that is not causing any viewstate.